# Best choice for the visual library in Salesforce in the case

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am to implement the following visual element in Salesforce:

[image]

What library should I use for that or are there lightning approaches which would be able to accomplish this? By the best choice I mean any choice which would allow me to complete this.

Comment: You might want to look at this.
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language I've used for connected graphs is [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)). Also in general, for drawing charts at the client-side [D3](https://d3js.org/) is great. And I notice that there is this project that unites the two: [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz). But this may be overkill - depends on exactly how much variation there is in what you are trying to render.

(Note that as these technologies draw in the browser using JavaScript the images will not appear in a PDF version of the page.)

Comment: Will I be able to make the circles clickable using the `D3`?

Comment: @oobarbazanoo Yes D3 allows interaction.

Comment: Do you know about [LDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com)? What disadvantages does it have in comparison with the `D3` ?

Comment: @oobarbazanoo You can use the SLDS styling (e.g. icons) but something has to generate the various diagram nodes.

Comment: Where could I find a tutorial (or something alike) which would walk me through setting up the `d3.js` for salesforce?

Comment: Google how to add a JavaScript library to Salesforce and then Google simple D3 examples.